# Position absolute and z-index in IE10

Tags: html, css, z-index, internet-explorer-10

Bit of a strange one, I'm trying to overlay a couple of links over an image, and only in IE (all versions) is it displaying them behind the image. Works in Chrome, Firefox, et al.

I've tried giving each element an appropriate z-index but it doesn't actually make any difference.

I swear I've done this a a million times before with issues.

Here's a JSFiddle for it:
http://jsfiddle.net/SY8xp/

```
<a href="#" class="logo-link-a"><span>Link 1</span></a>
<a href="#" class="logo-link-b"><span>Link 2</span></a>
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/212/43" width="212" height="43" alt="" id="logo" />

.logo-link-a span, .logo-link-b span {
    display: none;
}

.logo-link-a {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 25px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.logo-link-b {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 165px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 25px 0px 0px 50px;
}

#logo {
    margin-top: 30px;
}
```

Comment: I don't see `z-index` used anywhere

Comment: @Platinumpt -Did you noticed the ".logo-link-a span, .logo-link-b span" classes "display: none;".

Comment: No, it shouldn't be needed, but it's something I've tested.
The spans are hidden so that the text doesn't appear.

Comment: IE can be a bit weird with z-order. It could help to use `z-index` for each `position: absolute` element. `z-index: 1` for the very bottom and then `z-index: 2` to place an element above and so on.

Answer (score 5):

A hackish solution is to add a background-color to the `<a />` elements. Adding this to your jsfiddle's CSS worked:

```
.logo-link-a, logo-link-b {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0);
}
```

Comment: worked for me, could not click absolutely positioned links without background

Answer (score 0):

what's the reason to hide links over an image? you can wrap the image with `<a>` tag and create the link without much markup, you can also use image replacement that brings good results for the SEO  of page also

here some tricks to image replacement: http://css-tricks.com/css-image-replacement/

here a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9V5g8/1/

HTML:

```
<!-- option 1 -->
<a href="http://www.starbucks.com/"><img src="http://www.starbucks.com/static/images/global/logo.png" alt=""></a>

    <!-- option 2 -->
<div class="logo">
    <a href="http://www.starbucks.com/">
    <h1 class="img-replace">
      My Logo
    </h1>
    </a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
h1.img-replace {
  width: 85px; 
  height: 84px;
  background: url("http://www.starbucks.com/static/images/global/logo.png") no-repeat 0% 50%;
  text-indent: -9999px;
}
```

Comment: There are reasons I want to do it over the image.
I basically want to re-create an imagemap, if it was just 1 simple link wrapped around an image like your example it'd be easy. :)

Comment: you can use image maps generator around web